# Adding conditional CSS classes with ng-class in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, forms

I have a simple problem. I want to update my classes inside my inputs on form submit.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" ng-class="{'has-error': signup.$submitted && signup.name.$invalid}" type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name" required minlength="2" placeholder="Full Name">
</div>
```

Here's my app.js:

```
spinnrApp.controller('FormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function (scope, http, state){

  // get list of cities and store it to select
  http.get('cities.json').success(function(data){
    scope.cities = data;
  })

  // we will store all our form data in this object
  scope.formData = {};

  // function to process the form
  scope.processForm = function(isValid) {
    scope.$submitted = true;
    if(isValid && state.$current=='registration.spinnrapp') {
      state.go('registration.artist');
    } else if(isValid && state.$current=='registration.artist') {
      state.go('registration.share');
    } else if(!isValid && state.$current=='registration.artist') {
      alert('Please make sure you have selected an artist.');
    } else if(!isValid && state.$current=='registration.spinnrapp') {
      return;
    }
  };
}]);
```

When I execute my submit via `ng-click` calling this function, my `signup.$submitted` still stays as `false`. I also have a reference from this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xDIzC0A50cXxMpIHeP3C?p=preview

That Plunkr updates its class. Why isn't mine doing the same? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're setting scope.$submitted in the controller but the ng-class is using signup.$submitted.

Comment: The `name` of my `form` is `signup`. Isn't it just right to use the format of `formName.$control` the same how I used to validate the inputs such as `signup.name.$error.required`?

Comment: Also, using `scope.$submitted` did not work.

Comment: Use $submitted instead of scope.$submitted in the view

Comment: Thanks! I did it already. :)